# Retrieve the list of users in a Google Apps Domain with a non-admin account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-directory-api

Is it possible to retrieve the list of users in a Google Apps Domain with a **non-admin** account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-admin users can call [users.list(viewType=domain_public)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) which offers the same amount of details that the users see in the [domain contacts directory](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218?hl=en).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you think an admin account is.

Long ago the user roles were just "regular" and "admin". Now you can choose from a fine-grained set of permissions and define a role name for them. "Superadmin" is now a built-in role that has every permission possible.

So, if you define a role which can retrieve the user list and assign it to a user I wouldn't call it an admin account.

You need to be a true admin to do that, though :)

Comment: What is the minimum set of permissions need to retrieve the list of users in a Google Apps domain?

Comment: Just checking the read permission under the Users API section in the admin control panel is enough.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the other (excellent) answer, what I do in our domain is to create a full list of domain users in a spreadsheet with all necessary informations and run a script every night that updates the spreadsheet automatically. When I make a change (add or remove user) I can run the script manually to avoid temporary differences.

This script runs as "me" but any domain user has access to the list (I invite them to this shared doc when I create their account so it shows up in their *drive/shared with me* folder). With this solution I don't need to give special rights to any users.